# What is web-service and how to develop it

Tags: web-services

I am looking for some good starting point for developing web-service.

I have one application which has C++ library support using which I can get all the details of the product.

I am supposed to write web service SDK for the same.

Any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web services generally refer to a technique that allows code to be called via HTTP requests and responses. This is similar to a web page, except that what is returned from a web service is usually not HTML intended to be displayed in a browser - it is usually data of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

"Web Service" is one of those terms that means whatever the person saying it means.  Basically, its just a way to access data or functionality via http.  There's a few standardized methods - REST, SOAP for web services, or you can just serve up XML, JSON, or other data from a plain old server side web app.

What you'd want to do is investigate what form this Web Server you are supposed to write needs to be in (SOAP, REST, something else), and then go from there.

Comment: Thanks,So if i have small embeddable webserver which upon access say http://hostname:80/request return a json data, is this also called as web-service.

Comment: Yep, that'd be a web service.  BUT, I've found a lot of people read too many magazines, and mistakingly believe that 'web service' somehow requires using SOAP because that was the fad a couple of years ago.  So if your client/customer/boss wants a web service, you may want to clarify with them exactly what they mean by the term, in case they are expecting something specific.